# VMBox, Actual Size virtual size and Disk Usage give 3 diferent value

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Virtual Machine on Virtual box that has weird disk usage value, I'm trying to launch a Docker app. During npm install I get an error of insufficent space and can't understand why.

On my Disk Usage I can see that I have 80Gb in total and 5Gb left
[image: Disk Usage]

But when I click on it to inspect what takes 80Gb I see that it uses only 30Gb [image: link picture]

I don't understand how can I use 80Gb on the first menu and only 30Gb on the other one

And last but not least when I go to the Settings of the VM and check the disk I get "Actual Size" of 16Gb:  [image: "Actual Size" of 16Gb]

What is going on?

I'm sure that I don't use 80Gb because I have not a lot of things installed on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm sure that I dont uses 80Gb because I have not a lot of things
> installed on it

Almost for sure you allocated the entire 80Gb (that is, set the machine for 80 Gb) when setting up the machine (VM Apps allow this).

But your actual machine is 30Gb -Normal for my several virtual machines.

Here is a good article on VBOX disk allocation

[VBOX disk allocation](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=54411)

> The dynamic size and the VBox actual size reported really does not
> matter that much. It is how much free space you have in the Linux
> guest. Use df -h to check on occasion.
>
> If the actual size reported by VBox really is a bother to you then
> compact the guests drive. Just make sure you keep good backups. Other
> than that it will not really make a difference.

.

> I go to the Settings of the VM and check the disk I get 1 Gb

That is a support file not the Guest machine file.